# script to place all backup files(Full, diff &log) in same folder for all Databases in the server

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms, sql-server-2019, jobs

I have downloaded script from here : https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

Thank you for the SQL Server Backup script, it's creating separate folders & subfolders for each database.

But our project requirement: To place all backup files(Full, diff &log) in the same folder for all Databases in the server.

Please suggest if it is possible to change the maintenance script .

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

chaitu

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example:

```
exec [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'XXX'
,@BackupType = 'FULL'
,@Directory = '\\DESTINATION\sqlbackup$'
,@CopyOnly = 'Y'
,@Compress = 'Y'
,@CheckSum = 'Y'
,@init = 'Y'
,@DirectoryStructure = '{ServerName}${InstanceName}'
,@FileName = '{DatabaseName}.{FileExtension}'
,@logToTable = 'Y'
,@Execute = 'Y'
```

the key is to use this two options:

**,@DirectoryStructure = '{ServerName}${InstanceName}'**

**,@FileName = '{DatabaseName}.{FileExtension}'**

For reference, take a look at https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html#DirectoryStructure

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have passes the null value to DirectoryStucture . 

Now all backup files are placing on same folder . After set the CleanupTime value to  336 job is failing

Comment: Code modified: Modified in two places 

SET @ CreateJobs          = 'Y'          
SET @ BackupDirectory     = NULL        
SET @ CleanupTime         = 336          
SET @ OutputFileDirectory = NULL         
SET @ LogToTable          = 'Y'          



@ DirectoryStructure nvarchar(max) = NULL,--'{ServerName}${InstanceName}{DirectorySeparator}{DatabaseName}{DirectorySeparator}{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}',
@ AvailabilityGroupDirectoryStructure nvarchar(max) = NULL,-- ,

Comment: Error:Procedure dbo.DatabaseBackup, Line 2275  The value for the parameter @ CleanupTime is not supported. Cleanup is not supported if the token {DatabaseName} is not part of the directory. Msg 50000, Level 16, State 6, Server mssql-2019, Procedure dbo.DatabaseBackup, Line 2275 The value for the parameter @ CleanupTime is not supported. Cleanup is not supported if the token {BackupType} is not part of the directory. Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Server mssql-2019, Procedure dbo.DatabaseBackup, Line 2275  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.

Comment: as per error message, you have to keep folders and backup type to relay on cleanup feature